# The prop `loadingElement` is marked as required in `withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Component))

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting this error: "Failed prop type: The prop `loadingElement` is marked as required in `withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Component))`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Component))"

My Map.js file:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";    
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
} from "react-google-maps";

const MapWithAMarker = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={8}
    defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
  >
    <Marker
      position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
    />
  </GoogleMap>
));

<MapWithAMarker
  googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAIdFegRbfOurYRvDN8oQNJRmpKgIj48ZY&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
  loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
/>  
export default MapWithAMarker;
```

I'm importing this file in my other js file and putting

```
<div style={{width:400, hight:300, background:"red"}}>
          <MapWithAMarker />
        </div>
```

like this inside that js. And I'm getting the mentioned error.

Comment: <MapWithAMarker
  googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAIdFegRbfOurYRvDN8oQNJRmpKgIj48ZY&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
  loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  containerElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
  mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
/>  , here the prop you are passing might not be in expected way. 

please check the documentation once.

Comment: In the documentation it is in this order.  https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I'm calling it in my current project and it works just fine. Maybe this points you into the right direction.

```
const EmptyMap = compose(
    withProps({
      googleMapURL: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
      loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
      containerElement: <div style={{ height: `1000px`, display: 'none' }} />,
      mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
  )((props) => 
        <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={9}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: parseFloat(props.userLat), lng: parseFloat(props.userLng) }}
        >

        </GoogleMap>
);
```

Comment: @RiyaKapuria 

import { compose, withProps } from "recompose"

Comment: That error shouldn't stop the map from rendering. A failed GET request won't stop the page from rendering. You're just missing a favicon, it has nothing to do with the map. 

Is the map working now?